# If you create a table with 32 shards on one server, when you add more servers will those shards rebalance?

Tags: rethinkdb

When you have a one node cluster and you create a table with 32 shards, and then you add, say, 7 more nodes to the cluster, will those shards automatically migrate to the rest of the cluster so I have 4 shards per node ?

Is manual intervention required for this ?

How about the replicas created on one node ? Do those migrate to other nodes as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will be automatically redistributed.  In current versions of RethinkDB changing the number/distribution of replicas or changing shard boundaries will cause a loss of availability, so you have to explicitly ask for it happen (either in the web UI or with the command line administration tool).

Comment: Just a quick note: Rebalancing without a loss of availability is one of the higher priority things on our roadmap, so hopefully we'll be able to provide that soon.